# Reset estimator to a previous value scikit learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

```
tmp_classifier = classifier_nn.fit(x,y)
for elem in step:
    classifier_nn.partial_fit(new_x, new_y)
    classifier_nn = tmp_classifier
```

I would like to know if my estimator in this way is "reset" to the previous state that is the pre-trained classifier (classifier_nn.fit(x,y).

Comment: Check whether `classifier_nn is tmp_classifier` evaluates to `True` before you set `classifier_nn = tmp_classifier`, and/or check whether the value of `pickle.dumps(tmp_classifier)` is modified by the call to `classifier_nn.partial_fit(new_x, new_y)`. I'd normally check these myself if you had a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ;)

Comment: I have just checked with "is" and it is True. But the operator "is" check if they are the same object but doesn't check the content. 
I would like to know if i'm doing it well or not

Comment: Yes, the check on whether the value of `pickle.dumps(tmp_classifier)` is modified by the call to `classifier_nn.partial_fit(new_x, new_y)` would check whether the content is changing. If that value isn't modified, you're definitely resetting to the previous state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no resetting, because self.fit returns **self**, not a copy. In other words, tmp_classifier and classifier_nn are references to the same object. So when you are calling partial fit you are modifing both, and the final assignment does nothing.

What you have to do is **clone** classifier after fitting.

```
classifier_nn.fit(x,y)
tmp_classifier = deepcopy(classifier_nn)
for elem in step:
    classifier_nn.partial_fit(new_x, new_y)
    classifier_nn = tmp_classifier
```

should work.